# How to best implement a SetTimeout in console app?

Tags: c#, console-application

I would like to know how to best implement a `SetTimeout` using c# in my console app?

My Scenario is:

I upload a csv file using soap client, because the file size is large, I get returned a timeout exception.

Which is fine, because at this stage I would like my console app to pause for 15 minutes, and continue working again because i need to wait until the file has been uploaded.

Also if the file is still not uploaded after the 15 minutes I would like to check every minute to make sure the file has uploaded.

So the key is having a first 15 minute SetTimeout (like javascript) and check if the file is uploaded, else check every minute if the file is uploaded.

What is the best approach to implement this?

I have tried:

```
private Timer _timer;

_timer.Interval = ((1000 * 60) * 15);
_timer.Elapsed += IntervalElapsed;
_timer.Start();
```

The IntervalElapsed method is as follows:

```
private void IntervalElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){
   _timer.stop();
   // check if file has been uploaded
   var isFileUploaded = HasFileBeenUploaded();

   while(!isFileUploaded ){
      // perform setInterval until file has been uploaded
   }
}
```

However my IntervalElapsed method never gets called, the console app closes.

Comment: You should do that in Windows Service, Console application is not suitable for such tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple `Sleep` method instead of `Elapsed` method to achieve your goal

```
const int MINUTE = 1000 * 60;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15 * MINUTE);          
  while(!HasFileBeenUploaded())
  {               
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(MINUTE);
  }
}
```

--SJ

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to have something that stops the application from closing once you've finished setting up the timer, maybe try adding

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

at the end of your code, which will wait for user input before closing.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention this will be an automated scheduled task which will run daily so cant allow user intput

Comment: Okay, then maybe have a flag that you set when the task is done, and have a while loop that runs until the flag is set to true?

Comment: See having a while loop will be a big issue, because continuously it will try to check a web service to see if the file is uploaded, and that doesn't sound like a good idea. sorry.